# Who is the next vyasa after Ashwathama?

Tags: vyasa

Vedas are supposed to be divided in dwapara yuga. The current vyasa is Krishna-Dwaipayana, son of Parashara (who also was a Vyasa),and the author of Mahabharata who divided the vedas in dwapara yuga. The next vyasa after Krishna Dwaipayana Vyasa is Drona's son Ashwatthama.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp077.htm

> These are the twenty-eight elder Vyásas, by whom, in the preceding Dwápara ages, the Veda has been divided into four. In the next Dwápara, Drauńi (the son of Drońa) will be the Vyása, when my son, the Muni Krishńa Dwaipáyana, who is the actual Vyása, shall cease to be (in that character).

My question is, who is the next Vyasa after Ashwathama?

Comment: I don't know about who is Vyasa during 30th Mahayuga. But, Shiva Purana indirectly mentiones Suta will be Vyasa at final Mahayuga of current Manvantara. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This chapter](https://%20https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226594.html) from Shiva Purana describes Suta will explain how Lord Shiva annihilates the creation at end of Vaivasvata Manvantara.

> 76-77. Lord Rudra annihilates them I shall explain it at the end of Vaivasvata Kalpa. Thus I have mentioned all about the Manvantaras to you. It is a holy narrative conclusive to wealth and increase of the family.

I'm not sure but possibly it states that Suta will be future Vyasa (very long after Ashvatthama) in last Mahayuga of current Vaivasvata Manvantara.